# "But let me assure you, this, like any story worth telling is all about a girl."

Tags: meaning, spoken-english

In the 2002 *Spider-Man* movie, there is the following expression at 3:25

> But let me assure you, this, like any story worth telling is all about a girl.

Can anyone interpret this expression please?

Comment: Good stories often include a love element which, from a man's point of view is 'a story about a girl'. I assume that is what is meant.

Comment: Are you saying that any story will be good or worth good if it is about girl?

Comment: I'm saying that that is what the _quotation_ appears to mean!

Answer (score 1):

> "But let me assure you, this, like any story worth telling, is all about a girl."

This sentence uses *parenthetical commas* (although I think you missed one out of your quotation). This is worth noting because many people are more familiar with the use of brackets for parenthesis, and replacing them can often make the sentence clearer and easier to understand:

> But let me assure you, this (like any story worth telling) is all about a girl.

Parenthetical statements (the words within the brackets or commas) are usually additional information that explains or qualifies something being said. Although they may be useful or even essential, it should be possible to skip them entirely and the rest of the sentence be understood.

The main statement (excluding the parenthesis) is that an assurance that "this story is all about a girl".

As an aside, the narrator is adding that *any story worth telling* is about a girl.

Comment: Are you saying that any story will be good or worth good if it is about girl?

Comment: Astralbee isn't saying that.  But the narrator (a teenaged boy) is saying that.  The narrator is saying that "every story that is worth telling is about a girl", or equivalently. "if a story isn't about about girl, then its not worth telling".  (logically there could also be bad stories about girls, the narrator doesn't say.  The narrator might be wrong.)

Comment: @MojahidBinAlamSiper The narrator is a teenage boy. That's the perspective.